# Android gallery app thumbnail display

Tags: android, gallery, thumbnails

I am currently working on an app that interacts with android native gallery app. I am wondering how gallery app displays the image thumbnail, 
specifically

1. where does a thumbnail picture on the gallery come from?
2. if it is from the .thumbnail folder, how can I create my own thumbnail when I add image in the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

In android, thumbnail file created in DCIM/.thumbnails. This file can be several Gigabytes in size, depending on how many pictures you have. It is generated by the Android Gallery app.

Comment: Do you know how to update the thumbnail of a specific image in android ?

Comment: Thanks for replying the problem I am facing now is that I don't know how gallery app gets the thumbnail images, I tried to clear all the data in the MediaStore.Image.Thumbnail.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI table, however, there are still thumbnail image displaying in gallery.